# Delete rows on dataframes based on len(columns)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, delete-row

I have 3 dataframes that contains english_words, names and places. For each of the dataframes i am trying to remove all words with lengths less than 3 and i am using the following code:

```
english_words=english_words[english_words[0].map(len) >= 3]
names=names[names[0].map(len) >= 3]
places=places[places[0].map(len) >=3]
```

All the dataframes have just one column.
I am expecting to get new dataframes with only words that have length greater than or equal 3 but instead i am getting the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-d16d0eaf3a11> in <module>
----> 1 english_words=english_words[[(len(x) > 5) for x in english_words[0]]]
      2 names=names[names[0].map(len) >= 3]
      3 places=places[places[0].map(len) >=3]

<ipython-input-21-d16d0eaf3a11> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 english_words=english_words[[(len(x) > 5) for x in english_words[0]]]
      2 names=names[names[0].map(len) >= 3]
      3 places=places[places[0].map(len) >=3]

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Comment: Did you read the error...it is telling you exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed and this is the updated code:

```
english_words=english_words[[(len(str(x)) >=3) for x in english_words[0]]]
names=names[[(len(str(x)) >=3) for x in names[0]]]
places=places[[(len(str(x)) >=3) for x in places[0]]]
```